# コードのタイムアウトエラーの修正方法について

Tags: python, python3, アルゴリズム

コーディングテストの練習サイトCodilityの[CountSemiprimes](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/11-sieve_of_eratosthenes/count_semiprimes/)という問題を解いています。
[CountSemiprimesについて日本語で書かれた記事](http://codility-lessons-jp.blogspot.com/2015/03/lesson-9-countsemiprimes.html)

書いたコードを実行したところ、以下のエラーが出たため、出力の正しさを確認することができていません。
どのように修正するべきでしょうか。

```
Compilation successful.

Example test:    (26, [1, 4, 16], [26, 10, 20]) 
TIMEOUT ERROR  (running time: >5.00 sec., time limit: 5.00 sec.) 

Detected some errors.
```

書いたコード

```
import itertools
import math

def solution(N, P, Q):
    #素数の配列を作成
    all = []
    nonprime = []
    for i in range (2, round(N/2)+1):
        all.append(i)
        #素数かどうか
        for m in range(2, int(math.sqrt(i))):
            if i % m == 0:
                nonprime.append(i)
    prime = set(all) - set(nonprime)         

    #semiprimeの配列を作成
    semiprime = []
    #全ての２つの組み合わせを作成し、かけ算をしてN以下のものを配列に追加
    possible = list(itertools.combinations(prime,2))
    for j in range (len(possible)):
        pairs = possible[j]
        num = pairs[0] * pairs[1]
        if num <= N:
            semiprime.append(num)

    #P[]とQ[]の配列の範囲にあるsemiprimeの数を数える
    result = []
    for l in range(len(P)):
        count = 0
        for k in range(len(semiprime)):
            while semiprime[k] >= P[l] and semiprime[k] <= Q[l]:
                count += 1
        result.append(count)

    return result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

記載されたコードに以下のような実際に実行する部分を追加して、

```
def main():
    print(solution(26, [1, 4, 16], [26, 10, 20]))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

実際に確認した結果、`while semiprime[k] >= P[l] or semiprime[k] <= Q[l]: count += 1`の部分でループしていました。ループ判定条件に対応する部分が変動していないため、無限ループになっているようです。この部分を修正してください。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。修正いたしましたが、依然としてかなり計算量が多いようで、ローカル環境でも出力がされない状況です。

Comment: 修正した結果が[現在の編集内容](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/revisions/53630/2)でしょうか？同様に実行してみたのですが、やはり無限ループになっているようです（ `count += 1`の次の行に`print(count, semiprime)`などしてみると動作が分かると思います）。 / 最初の質問内容からソースコードが変わっている時点で別の質問として切り分けたほうが良いかもしれません。